# DirectionsRenderer for origin and destination as props

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am using DirectionsRenderer react-google-maps library to render destination between two points. I would like to pass custom props for the origin and destination inside the lifecycle componentDidMount function, but the pathCoordinates for origin and destination throws an error to say undefined. What is the best way to pass this information to render destination and origin marker locations.

```
... all the right imports

const Map = compose(
    withGoogleMap,
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
            const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            DirectionsService.route({
                origin: pathCoordinates[0],
                destination: pathCoordinates[1],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            }, (result, status) => {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    this.setState({
                        directions: result,
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
                }
            });
        }
    })
)(props =>
    <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={13}
        defaultCenter={props.pathCoordinates[0]}
    >
        {props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions} />}
    </GoogleMap>
);

class MapOverlay extends Component {
    render() {
        const trip = this.props.trip;

        return (
            trip.status !== '' ?
                <Map
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={styles.map} />}
                    pathCoordinates={
                        [
                            { lat: trip.pickUp.coordinates[1], lng: trip.pickUp.coordinates[0] },
                            { lat: trip.dropOff.coordinates[1], lng: trip.dropOff.coordinates[0] }
                        ]
                    }
                />
                : null
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those props could be accessed via `this.props.pathCoordinates`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    DirectionsService.route({
      origin: this.props.pathCoordinates[0], 
      destination: this.props.pathCoordinates[1], 
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    }, (result, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        this.setState({
          directions: result,
        });
      } else {
        console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
      }
    });
}
```

**[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/k07zx6m04o)**